# Serial port IOException: Accessis Denied

Tags: unity-game-engine, serial-port

I have a UI panel with some dropdowns on it to select values for a serial port (Port name, baud rate, etc..) when I click 'Connect' the following code is run, these values are used to initialize and then open a Serial Port. First time I click 'Connect' everything good, no errors.  When I open the panel and click 'Connect' again I get an error IOException: Access is denied.  The error is at this line:

if (sp.IsOpen==false) sp.Open();

I am sure that I am not trying to open a port that is already open.

Have tried closing all the ports in another method before the UI panel gets opened.

I expect to be able to open the UI panel and run the code more than once.

Tried closing all the ports before calling this method.

`````
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using TMPro;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;

public class ReadPortData : MonoBehaviour       // Comes here when 'connect' is clicked, to start reading serial port data
{
    public TMP_Dropdown portName;
    public TMP_Dropdown baudRate;
    public TMP_Dropdown dataBits;
    public TMP_Dropdown stopBits;
    public TMP_Dropdown parity;

    private string spName;
    private int baud;
    private int dB;
    private int sB;
    private string pRity;

    public SerialPort sp;

    public void ReadDataFromBHI()
    {
        //   First get the values that were selected on the pnlComms dropdowns

        sp = new SerialPort();

        spName = portName.options[portName.value].text;
        baud = int.Parse(baudRate.options[baudRate.value].text);
        dB = int.Parse(dataBits.options[dataBits.value].text);
        sB = int.Parse(stopBits.options[stopBits.value].text);
        pRity = parity.options[parity.value].text;


        sp.PortName = spName;
        sp.BaudRate = baud;
        sp.DataBits = dB;

        switch (sB)
        {
            case 0: sp.StopBits = StopBits.None; break;
            case 1: sp.StopBits = StopBits.One; break;
            case 2: sp.StopBits = StopBits.Two; break;
        }

        switch (pRity)
        {
            case "None": sp.Parity = Parity.None; break;
            case "Odd": sp.Parity = Parity.Odd; break;
            case "Even": sp.Parity = Parity.Even; break;
        }

        // Next open the port and activate the data recieved event handler

        Debug.Log("made it to ReaddatafromBHI");
        Debug.Log(sp.PortName);
        Debug.Log(sp.BaudRate);
        Debug.Log(sp.DataBits);
        Debug.Log(sp.StopBits);
        Debug.Log(sp.Parity);
        Debug.Log(spName + sp.IsOpen);

        sp.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(DataIn);
        if (sp.IsOpen==false) sp.Open();
    ````}
`````

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure since I haven't work with serial ports before, but I have a gut feeling that since every time you are creating a new instance of `SerialPort` it is marked as closed, meaning you will always get `IsOpen` as false.

Then when you try to open it, it's already open and you get this error, which looking in MSDN says:

```
The current process, or another process on the system, already has the specified COM port open either by a SerialPort instance or in unmanaged code.
```

Try maybe saving the `SerialPort` instance and using it as sort of a singleton (Also I can see that in MSDN [this is what they do](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport?view=netframework-4.8)).

Also, I think you should check if the port is open at the start as a sanity check, and stop there instead of doing everything and just at the end.